# excel help: trying to create a date formula

Tags: excel, formula, any

i want to create a formula like this, 
**=DATE(YEAR(any)),MONTH((any)),14)**
i don't care about year or month only the **day**.
apparently excel doesn't let me add "any" as a fuction. can someone please help me?

Comment: Just what do you mean by `any`? Random?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=DATE(RANDBETWEEN(1,9999),RANDBETWEEN(1,12),14)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use the current year and month, use this formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), 14)
```

However, the month does matter if you wanted to put 31 for the day (or 29/30 if the month happens to be February), so you might want to just always use a specific year and month that will allow for maximum flexibility, such as:

```
=DATE(2000,1,14)
```

One thing I would suggest is to ask yourself why you are storing this as a date in the first place if you only care about the day of the month. You could just store `14` and label the column "Day of Month". To better answer your question, it would be helpful to know what are you actually doing with these dates.